# If $P(E|F)=P(E|F^c)$ then $E$ and $F$ are independent.

Tags: probability

If $P(E|F)=P(E|F^c)$ then $E$ and $F$ are independent.

**My work**
$P(E|F)=P(E|F^c)\implies\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)}=\frac{P(E\cap F^c)}{P(F^c)}\implies\frac{P(E\cap F)-P(E\cap F)P(F)}{P(F)}=P(E\cap F^c)\implies \frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)}=P(E\cap F^c)+P(E\cap F)$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You simply have:

$$
P(E) = P(F)P(E|F)+P(F^c)P(E|F^c) = P(F)P(E|F)+(1-P(F))P(E|F)=P(E|F)
$$
which is enough to show that $E$ and $F$ are independent.

To follow up on what you did:
$$
P(E\cap F^c)+P(E\cap F)=P(E)
$$
and
$$
\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)}=P(E|F)
$$

Hence the result.

Comment: Why $P(E\cap F)+P(E\cap F^c)=P(E)$? i don't see that part.

Comment: @Bvss12 What is $P(E\cap(F\cup F^c))$?

Comment: It is a property: if $(F_i)$ is a partition of $\Omega$ (that is: $P(\cup_i F_i) = 1$ and $F_i \cap F_j = \emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$), then $P(E) = \sum_i P(E\cap F_i)$ .

Comment: Oh, thanks  for all@BillO'Haran

Comment: @Bvss12 You are very much welcome. The property is called [law of total probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). Took me a while to find the Wikipedia page.